# How can I add multiple items in windows forms combobox in design mode?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have visual studio 2017. In an older project in few combo-boxes there are items entered in design mode (countries, etc...).

I would like to copy this items and paste them in combo-box in new projects, but I don't know how this could be accomplished.

I can create text file and add items with code, but if I want to add them in design mode I could do this one item per line. Is there some property that I didn't enable?
Thanks

Comment: Have you try just ctrl+C  ctrl+V the combox with item to new project?

Comment: I want to copy more than 1 item. If I do Ctrl+V I could only copy first item on the list. This is what is bothering me, why doesn't paste all items.

Comment: In UI edit mode,  select combo-box and there have a play icon on it, get into it (edit item)and copy all the item to the new one?

Comment: It is simple copy/paste from the Collection Editor, hard to see what the problem might be.

Comment: I tried play icon, and I have also tried collection editor. I can't figure it out why is only for current item background white, and rest is grey. Both in play and collection editor.

Comment: Open up the Form's `designer.cs` file (in the IDE), find your ComboBox, there you'll see something like `this.comboBox1.Items.AddRange(new object[] {"Value1", "Value2", "Value3"});`. Copy this line and paste it somewhere else (adjusting the ComboBox name, of course). Otherwise, copy the ComboBox control itself: when you paste it back, the original items will follow.

Comment: yes, this could work. I think that this is the best answer.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps to add items to combobox in designer mode:

1. Add a combobox.
2. Right-click and click properties.
3. In the Properties tab, scroll down to 'items'.
4. You will find 'collection' written on its extreme right.
5. Click on the small button to its right(The on with three dots).
6. A box will open up.
7. Enter the items in it.
   Remember, a new item on every line.
8. If you have required items typed in a .txt file, you can copy and paste it in this dialog.
9. Enter new item on new line.

DONE!

**EDIT:**

As of today, there is no possible way to populate combobox with a text file in the Visual Studio's designer mode itself.

If you need help with code to populate combobox with text file, you can edit the question or comment this answer and I'll be happy to help you.

Comment: This isn't exactly what I wanted. I don't want to add one item at a time.

Comment: @Willow:       Pls wait for some time and i'll try to find something.

Comment: @Willow:       I have edited the question. Pls read the **EDIT** part.

Comment: @D J Thank you for your effort. I solved this with code, created class, method and populate combo-box with method result. Thanks again.

Comment: @Willow:       You are welcome. If you need you can also create a custom combobox which can be populated by a .txt file. Another possible solution!